# How to replace language UniqueSeoCode from url

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-3.80

How to replace language UniqueSeoCode from url.

I need to manage language UniqueSeoCode from plugin. how to replace from plugin. if user selection any language from website but i need to redirect to only one language then how to do this ?

I try to do this from action filter based on CommonController of public website and then from this action filter i redirect to specific url. is this proper way or if you have any another proper way let me suggest please.

I need to redirect to customer to spefic language when customer directly open website(e.g. www.google.com) at the time in url does not contain any language so at this time i need to use my specif language.
now how to check that url contain language seocode or not.

if i use actionfilter on commonController at that time i always get language code? how to manage ?

Answer (score 0):

UniqueSeoCode in url is not needed. NopCommerce can detect visitor browser language and browse website in this language. You can enable this option like below.

To configure localization settings go to Configuration  → Settings  → General settings
Tick the checkbox Automatically detect language for detecting language based on customer browser settings.